# Scope from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to find a workaround so I can filter my `@events` by the `.is_near` method then sort them by the `.sort_today` scope, in that order.

Individually they both work, and I can tack `.is_near` to the end of the scope with no problem, but then my results are resorted by the default sort parameters in `.is_near`, and I need to them to be sorted by `.sort_today`.

Is there a way to ignore how `.is_near` returns/resorts my results? Or someway to chain them together like `@events.is_near(session[:city]).sort_today`? Currently I get this error when chaining them like that: **undefined method `sort_today' for #Array:0x007f8ca3c673c0**

Here's my models:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :latitude, :longitude

  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy

  geocoded_by :address

  def self.is_near(city)
    self.near(city, 20, :units => :km).map(&:events).flatten
  end
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :details, :start_time, :end_time, :date, :cost, :venue_id

  belongs_to :venue

  scope :is_today, where(:date => Date.today)
  scope :sort_today, is_today.order(:start_time)

  class << self
    def is_near(*args, &block)
      Venue.is_near(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

So `Venue` is geocoded by the RubyGeocoder gem and it has all the events. The `.is_near` method has to be in `Venue` because the latitude and longitude properties are there. The `.is_near` method at the bottom of `Event` is essentially a redirect. (I tried to get delegate to work, but this was the only way I could do it)

Here's my controllers:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @events = Event.sort_today.is_near(session[:city]) #returns results but sorted wrong
    #@events = Event.is_near(session[:city]).sort_today #returns undefined method `sort_today' error
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_city
  def set_city
    unless session[:city].present?
      session[:city] = request.location.city
    end
  end
end
```

The `set_city` method just gets what city the user enters through a input field.

**Edit:** Here's a link to the Ruby Geocoder documentation: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the scope location from in the `Venue` model to the `Event` model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :latitude, :longitude

  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy

  geocoded_by :address
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :details, :start_time, :end_time, :date, :cost, :venue_id

  belongs_to :venue

  scope :is_today, where(:date => Date.today)
  scope :sort_today, is_today.order(:start_time)
  scope :is_near, lambda {|city| Venue.near(city, 20, :units => :km).map(&:events).flatten }
end
```

And this works in my controller: `@events = @events.sort_today.is_near(session[:city])`

TLDR: I removed the redirect methods and replaced it with a lambda

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.map(&:events)` in `Venue.is_near`, that returns an `Array` rather than an `AcitveRecord::Relation`. That means when `is_near` is called, the database query is done immediately rather than lazily evaluating the query with chained methods.

I can see a few different ways to deal with this.

One is to call `Venue.is_near(session[:city])` and then use `Array`'s `sort_by` method on the returned array of `Event`s to sort in Ruby. This will probably be slower than doing it in the database.

The other way is doing a [`join`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) to move the evaluation of the `where` clause and the `order by` clause into one database query. I'm not very familiar with the geocoder gem, so I'm not sure if this applies. Essentially I'd want to be able to [specify a condition on the join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables):

In Event:

```
def self.nearby_sorted(location)
  Event.joins(:venue).where(venue: {near: location}).order("events.start_time")
end
```

but I'm not sure if the geocoder gem will let you do hash conditions like that :-/ Give it a try and report back?

Comment: I'm getting this error: **PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "venue"** LINE 1: ..."."venue_id" WHERE "events"."category_id" = 1 AND "venue"."n... SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "venues" ON "venues"."id" = "events"."venue_id" WHERE "events"."category_id" = 1 AND "venue"."near" = 'Vancouver' AND (venue_id not in (3)) ORDER BY events.start_time.
Not sure if that's from Geocoder or not.

Comment: Is it possible to use something other than `.map`? I've noticed it's seems to be sending a lot of queries back and forth to the database, which I imagine will make things move slowly once there's a lot of data in there.

Comment: re: your first comment, yeah, that sort of thing is what I was afraid of. I don't think a valid query is getting constructed. Re: your second comment, that's a common problem in rails called the "n+1 query problem" that you can solve by adding `.includes(:events)` before the `.map` in the chained query. This will eagerly load all the events for the venues in one query instead of n.